# Simplification of long trigonometric expression taking a long time

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization, trigonometry

I have tried to Simplify as well as FullSimplify a long trigonometric expression to get a simplified form of the expression but it takes a very long time almost hours and sometimes it also shows error as 'Exceeding time constraint more than 300 seconds'. Please suggest how can we solve this and get the simplified form of the expression. And if if there any other way to simplify trigonometric expression please suggest. Is there any way to shorten the run time and get the output quickly. Here is the trigonometric expression which we want to simplify

````
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[ 2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] - 
 4 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - 
    Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta],
    12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - 
    Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta],
    12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - 
    Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta],
    12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - 
    Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta],
    12]]^4 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^3 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^2 Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^3 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]] Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]] Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]] Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]] Cos[\[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 + 
 2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^3 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^3 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 - 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]] Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 
   13]] Cos[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Cos[
   Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]]^2 Sin[\[Delta]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[2 Subscript[\[Theta], 12]] Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 + 
 2 Cos[\[Delta]]^2 Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Cos[
   2 \[Delta] + Subscript[\[Phi], \[Mu]] - 
    Subscript[\[Phi], \[Tau]]] Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 12]]^2 Sin[
   Subscript[\[Theta], 13]]^2 Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 23]]^4 ```
````

Comment: Copy and paste your code correctly. There is some error.

Comment: See if its coming correctly now.

Comment: Simplify your expressions at each step, do not wait until outputs get too complicated to be easily simplified. Your expression is very long and complex and has lots of variables so it is not a surprise it takes a long time to be simplified. Also it is better to use `x17` instead of `Subscript[x, 17]`. Try to avoid using `Subscript`.

Comment: Do you know there is a particular simplification in that result that you know should be done? Like `expr1*Sin[expr2]^2+expr1*Cos[expr2]^2` == `expr1`? Or are you just thinking that it should somehow be five times simpler and so Mathematica should try every possible simplification idea it has  all 4630 symbols in that and do all that in 20 seconds? If you know it is the first then it may be possible, maybe not, to try something like `hugeexpression//.expr1_*Sin[expr2_]^2+expr1_*Cos[expr2_]^2->expr1` and carefully check to see if that worked or not. I quickly got a 23% smaller result with that.